# Asp.net MVC3 Appropriate Model Passing VB.net

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I'm quite new to MVC and while I've been trying to follow the best practices , I believe I may not be understanding certain fundamentals of either

-a. Using models and viewmodels appropriately
-b. Passing models into a controller for validation purposes.

The general purpose of my program is to select a stored procedure from a list of stored procedures, create a form where the user can fill out all the appropriate input variables, and then to execute that stored procedure.  The tool is for non-technical people, so I'm eventually going to have to do a good deal of input validation.

As such I have four models:  A Script Model, a Parameter Model, a Parameter Enum model and a Query Model, and two viewmodels: a paramviewmodel that generates the form to fill out, and a scriptviewmodel that creates a listbox filled with the possible script choices. I am using a prewritten database system to fill out my viewmodels in an init method in my controller (which I'm not sure is the proper way to do this?).

The viewmodels are as follows:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class ScriptViewModel

    Public Property SelectedItemId As Integer
    Public Property Scripts As DataTable
    Public Property ScriptList As List(Of ScriptModel)

    Sub InitScriptData()
        ' Fills the data from an outside database.  
        ' And fills out the properties above.  Does nothing else
    End Sub

End Class
```

Other One

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class ParamViewModel

    Public Property Params As DataTable
    Public Property ParamEnums As DataTable
    Public Property ParameterList As List(Of ParameterModel)
    Public Property ParamEnumList As List(Of ParamEnumModel)
    Public Property ParamEnumDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of ParamEnumModel))

    Sub InitParamData(ByVal Script_Index As String)
        ' Uses an outside database
        ' Fills out all the above variables    
    End Sub
End Class
```

Their associated views look like so:

Script:

```vb
@ModelType Scripter.ScriptViewModel
@Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the errors and try again.")
@Using (Html.BeginForm("ParamChoice", "Parameter", FormMethod.Post))
    @<div>
    @Html.ListBox("ScriptListBox", New SelectList(Model.ScriptList, "Script_Index", "CustomerScriptName"), New With {.class = "LargeListBox", .title = "LargeListBox"})
    </div>
    @<input type="submit" value="Execute Script" />
End Using
```

ParamChoice:

```vb
@ModelType Scripter.ParamViewModel
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "ParamChoice"
End Code

<h2>ParamChoice</h2>

<!-- Helper Method defined in App_Code that creates a form with a dynamic number of fields of appropriate input types -->
@HelperMethods.CreateVariableInputParameterFields(Model.ParameterList, Model.ParamEnumDictionary)
```

Said Helper (This is where my main confusion lies) (Note, the inherits helperpage refers to a class that allows me to use htmlhelpers in an @helper in app_code)

```vb
@inherits Scripter.HelperPage

@Imports System.Web.Mvc
@Imports System.Web.Mvc.Html

@helper CreateVariableInputParameterFields(ByVal ParamList As List(Of Scripter.ParameterModel), ByVal EnumDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Scripter.ParamEnumModel)))
    Dim item As Scripter.ParameterModel

    @Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the errors and try again.")

    Using (Html.BeginForm("QueryServer", "Query", FormMethod.Post))

    Dim iterator As Integer = 0
    Dim ParamValue(ParamList.Count) As String
    Dim ParamName(ParamList.Count) As String
    Dim ParamType(ParamList.Count) As String

    For Each item In ParamList
        If (String.Compare(item.ParamType, "Int") = 0 Or String.Compare(item.ParamType, "String") = 0) Then
            @<br />
            @Html.Label(item.ParamName)
            @Html.TextBox("ParamValue", Nothing, New With {.class = "text-box", .id = CStr(iterator)})
            @Html.Hidden("ParamName", item.ParamName, New With {.id = CStr(iterator)})
            @Html.Hidden("ParamType", item.ParamType, New With {.id = CStr(iterator)})
            iterator += 1
        ElseIf (String.Compare(item.ParamType.ToString, "Enum") = 0) Then
            Dim tlist = EnumDictionary.Item(item.Param_Index)
            @<br />
            @Html.Label("label", item.ParamName, New With {.class = "display-label"})
            @Html.DropDownList("ParamValue", New SelectList(tlist, "EnumValue", "EnumValue"), New With {.id = CStr(iterator)})
            @Html.Hidden("ParamName", item.ParamName, New With {.id = CStr(iterator)})
            @Html.Hidden("ParamType", item.ParamType, New With {.id = CStr(iterator)})
            iterator += 1
        Else
            @<br />
            @Html.Label("label", item.ParamName, New With {.class = "display-label"})
            @Html.CheckBox("ParamValue", Nothing, New With {.id = CStr(iterator)})
            @Html.Hidden("ParamName", item.ParamName, New With {.id = CStr(iterator)})
            @Html.Hidden("ParamType", item.ParamType, New With {.id = CStr(iterator)})
            iterator += 1
        End If
    Next

    @Html.Hidden("Script_Index", ParamList.Item(0).Script_Index)

    @<div>
        <input type="submit" value="Query Server"/>
    </div>
    Html.EndForm()
End Using
End helper
```

Script Controller as an example of what I've been doing:

```vb
Namespace Scripter
    Public Class ScriptController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Dim Test As New ScriptViewModel
            Test.InitScriptData()

            Return View(Test)
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Sorry everything above is so ugly haha, I'm trying to work out the functionality.  Also, I think this may be too much code in the view, even though most of it is display code.

Anyways, I have two main questions.  One, does creating a model in my controller, calling an init method on it, and then passing it to the view make any sense in an mvc context (if not, how would I proceed?). Two, if I want to perform validation on the form I output in my htmlhelper, but I want to use my query model validation (and not my paramviewmodel), how can I do that?  Most of the examples I've seen involve a controller that recieves an appropriate model variable, and the binding is performed outside the controller itself.  They then just check modelstate.  Is there any way I could do something similar here?

Please feel free to shoot down my code here.  I'm super new to this (both vb.net and mvc) and haven't yet had a chance to pick up a book.  I've been cobbling together sources online, but I'm sure I'm doing quite a few things wrong.

Edit: Is there any way I can make the syntax highlighting less crappy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a view model is not intended to have Init methods that is going to fetch data from a database. A view model is a standard POCO class in most cases containing properties that will hold the data that the particular view needs to work with.

On the other hand you could have one or more domain models that will be responsible for retrieving information from various data sources.

And the controller action will be responsible for querying your domain models and their various methods in order to finally build a specific view model that will be handled to the view for displaying. A view model could represent data that is aggregated from multiple domain models and various data sources.

So basically here's pseudo-code of how a standard GET controller action might look like:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim model1 As DomainModel1 = ... fetch the domain model from somewhere
    Dim model2 As DomainModel2 = ... fetch the domain model from somewhere

    Dim vm As ViewModel = ... map all the domain models to a single view model specifically designed for the view

    Return View(vm)
End Function
```

Here the domain models are responsible for bringing the data from the various data sources that you are working with (databases, files, remote web services, ...). The view model is just a projection of this data in an adapted way for the view.

Comment: Let's say I've done the above and passed a viewmodel to the view, which builds my parameters form (It shouldn't be too bad to change this in my code).  If I want to post that form to a different controller, and validate it, would the modelstate.isvalid use the viewmodel or would it use the model named similarly to the controller(my querymodel in this case)?  I guess I don't follow the model binding associated with input validation.

Comment: The first level of validation is on the view model. Your POST controller action takes the view model as parameter. Your view model properties are decorated with the appropriate validation attributes. Inside the controller action you test if the ModelState.IsValid.

Comment: Or to put it a different way, does my viewmodel need to contain empty data structures that I can hold the input data in (as well as the parameter data to generate the form), or can I have another model that represents that data?  I'm speaking in the sense of validation.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What do you qualify as *empty data structures*? The view models is in most cases a simple POCO class with a couple of properties decorated with validation attributes. In terms of validation, as I said, the first level is the one you perform on the view model. Then you invoke some method on your domain model or repository to perform the actual processing. You could also have domain validation logic in your service layer, but that's not related to ASP.NET MVC. Inside the POST controller action you test if the view model is valid and call service method.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not grasping the concept of a viewmodel.  When you say map the domain models to a single view specific model, do you mean have the domain models access the database and fill out their appropriate variables, pass those to the viewmodel, and then use the viewmodel to display the view?  If so, my question is does the viewmodel also need to have fields representing my possible form inputs, which it would fill when the user submits their form?

Comment: Exactly. You have very well grasped the concept of view model. The view is strongly typed to the view model (`@ModelType` directive). The HTML input fields are related to the view model. The view never *touches* the domain. All the interaction between the domain and the view model happens inside the controller action. It takes as input/output only view models.

Comment: Is it possible to map the HTML Input fields to a different model, which I send to a different controller?  Would doing that even make sense?

Comment: Of course. All you have to do is to use the proper overload of the `Html.BeginForm` helper which allows you to specify a controller name and an action name. Then the target POST controller action could work with the same view model. A view model is tied to a view.